# How can I import and overload existing React Native component in a native module

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a native module with React Native.

What I want to do is take an existing React Native component, overload it, and add new props that perform native actions.

For example, I want to import a React Native Text component into a native module, overload it, and have it return a new prop while retaining the default React Native prop.

How can I import and overload existing React Native component in a native module? I would appreciate a simple guide for iOS and Android.

Comment: You can’t do that. But what you can do you could fork react-native (https://github.com/facebook/react-native)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate your native module in ObjC you need to create two files e.g. **MyModule.m and MyModule.h**.
You might be prompted to create a bridge file, **do it**.

Inside MyModule.m
`import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>  import <React/RCTViewManager.h>`

Create a custom ViewManager MyModule.m:

```
@interface MyTextManager : RCTViewManager
@end

@implementation MyTextManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(text, NSString) // This will export the default <Text> Properties

- (UIView *)view {
    return [UILabel new]; // You can also use RCTTextView for multiline text
}

@end
```

Usage in ReactNative

```
import { requireNativeComponent } from 'react-native';

const MyText = requireNativeComponent('MyText');

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <MyText
      style={{ fontSize: 16, color: 'red' }}
      text="Hello from Native Module"
    />
  );
};
```